# Use select_multiple to populate choices in select_one using the same list

Tags: arcgis-survey123

I have a long list of names that will be tedious to scroll through for every detail record (a repeat).  To avoid this, I want to have a `select_multiple` where I can choose several names that then populates a `select_one` with only those values, which is much more streamlined.

I believe this should be the same as the `"Select Multiple"` group in the `Cascading Selects` sample form in `Survey123 Connect`.  The sample there doesn't appear to be working.

I'm running `theme-grid` and my Survey/Choices tabs are...

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

EDIT:  based on what I have found, the `choice_filter` should be functional via both of the attempts I made (lines 3 and 4).  The `select_one` with `name=Fisher2` attempt is *partially* functional in that it will display a single value, but fails after the second Fisher is selected. Some extra info on choice_filters and cascading selects can be found [here](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/survey123/desktop/create-surveys/xlsformcascadingselects.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_26C265B8FFAC45C6BFDD89652C1BA7CF) and [here (better info)](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/survey123-tricks-of-the-trade-choice-filters/ba-p/894046)